# ¿Como hago un instalador para un programa con una BD de Sqlite?

Tags: c#, base-de-datos, visual-studio, sqlite, instalacion

mi problema es que he creado un programa que tira de una BD de SQLite integrada en la carpeta del proyecto, a la hora de hacer un instalador usando el setup de visual studio, pese a que parece que me lo instala, una vez lo ejecuto, me aparece el símbolo de carga encima del cursor, pero no se abre, alguien sabe que podría[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] estar haciendo mal?

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. Revisa el visor de eventos para ver si hay errores asociados a tu instalador.

Comment: lo he revisado y me sale todo correcto, la cosa es que haciendo el mismo procedimiento con el proyecto sin BD no me da ese problema y si que se ejecuta.

Comment: Sin más datos, es difícil incluso adivinar qué puede ser. No conozco mucho sobre C#, pero deberíá existir la opción para que el instalador genere un log.